# Screaming small, medium and large crowds. 

Tags: libraries, vocals

Does anyone know where to get or order libraries with small, medium and large crowds screaming in different believable variations? scared, ambient, anxoius, etc. The recordings must be recorded in a neutral room, without indicating size, indoor or outdoor feel. Any recording studios up for that task? It´s to be used in a game.

Answer (score 2):

that's the kind of stuff we tend to bring loop group in for, as do a lot of places.  As such there's probably a little less demand for library stuff than there would otherwise be.

Do you have access to a suitable recording space?  You'll be waaay better off rolling your own with this type of thing.

Comment: What is loop group?

Comment: a bunch of people that come into a studio to record non-sync specific group and crowd reactions to picture.